# cannot import Lungdataset from dataset package in python

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

I am watching a video in which Lungdataset is imported from the dataset package. this dataset is imported as in the below picture
[image]

but when I try to do that through the below code

```
import dataset
from dataset import LungDataset
```

it gives the below Error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'LungDataset' from 'dataset' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/dataset/**init**.py)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I didn't find this dataset in "dataset". Maybe the code should be:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
load_dataset(name='lung-cancer')
```